# Who first measured the increase of mass with speed?

Tags: physics

Wiki (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_mass) says that:

> Thomson (1893) noticed that electromagnetic momentum and energy of charged bodies, and therefore their masses, depend on the speed of the bodies as well.

and:

> electrostatic energy behaves as having some sort of momentum and "apparent" electromagnetic mass, which can increase the ordinary mechanical mass of the bodies, or in more modern terms, the increase should arise from their electromagnetic self-energy. This idea was worked out in more detail by Oliver Heaviside (1889),[3] Thomson (1893),[4] George Frederick Charles Searle (1897),[5] Max Abraham (1902),[6] Hendrik Lorentz (1892, 1904),

ans most of all that:

```
This was discussed in connection with the proposal of the electrical origin of matter, so **Wilhelm Wien (1900)**,[9] and Max Abraham (1902),[6] **came to the conclusion that the total mass of the bodies is identical to its electromagnetic mass.**
```

Now , I have a few related questions regarding the issue:

- who first measured the increase of mass with speed? do you have any details on the experiment?
- why only Einstein is credited with the formula, when since 1900 the equivalence had been found( proved?)
- is it possible that in 1905 Einstein referred to rest mass i.e. matter could be transformed into em energy? it was only in 1930 that a pair was converted into light, did anyone nefore 1930 anticipate that?